# Cant Find Form Inputs in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Missing something very elementary here, I have a basic form im testing on that I want to check if a field is empty :

```
    <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!--#include file="Connections/Logistics.asp" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta "http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"">
  <title>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</title>
<script src="img/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
var fields  = $(":input").serializeArray();
$.each(fields,function(i,e){
    if(e.value === ""){
        $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );  
        event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="1" id="in1" value="hi">
    <input type="text" name="2" id="in2" value="asdf"/>
    <input type="text" name="3"id="in3" value="bye">
    <span></span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is able to work, however I would like to know which field in particular is blank and add either a red outline or text inside indicating it is required. Any thoughts?

[JFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nf4xuehx/1/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking us to *"send them t3h cod3z"*

Comment: Thank you all for the help that was it. I ended up using serializeArray() which was pulling JSON data, e.value would work becaues that was an element value in JSON, but I could not get other items from that field like .val(). @Phil I was not asking people to send me "cod3z", I just wanted thoughts and resources on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Those reasons are still off-topic for SO but I'm glad you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#form input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
         alert('this field is empty');
        $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
    }else{
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/nf4xuehx/3/)

Answer (score 2):

try this

js

```
  var fields = $('#form input[type="text"]');

    $.each(fields, function(i, f) {
        if($(f).val() == '') {
            $(f).closest('span')
            .append('<span style="color: red;">IS EMPTY</span>'); // show something   
        }
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fyvh9j5k/)

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with this line `event.preventDefault();`, but you had no event to provide that data: Here is what to update in your fiddle:

```
<form id="form" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="1" id="in1" value="hi">
    <input type="text" name="2" id="in2"/>
    <input type="text" name="3"id="in3" value="bye">
    <span></span>
    <input id="show-result" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


<script>
    var fields  = $(":input").serializeArray();
    $('#form').on('submit',function(event){
        $.each(fields,function(i,e){
            if(e.value === ""){
                $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```